# How do you add a reaction to the response of a slash command?

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

I'm facing **problems** trying to add a reaction to the bot's response when it responds to a slash command I entered.

```
@bot.slash_command(name='test', description="Test.")
async def test(ctx):
  msg = await ctx.send("Hello.")
  await msg.add_reaction('')
```

As you can see it's supposed to add a reaction to it's own message.
But I get this **error**:

`nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'PartialInteractionMessage' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'`

Please tell me how do I add a reaction to a slash command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

As per the error, `ctx.send` is returning a `PartialInteractionMessage`. From [the docs](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#partialinteractionmessage):

> This does not support most attributes and methods of `nextcord.Message`. The `fetch()` method can be used to retrieve the full `InteractionMessage` object.

### Code

```py
@bot.slash_command(name='test', description="Test.")
async def test(ctx):
  msg = await ctx.send("Hello.")
  full_msg = await msg.fetch()
  await full_msg.add_reaction('')
```